# WAMP - Put online while being offline?

Tags: php, wamp

If I'm on a local network is there a URL that I can type that will allow all users on the local network to view a local hosted website?

There is one feature called put online but I would need to be connected to the internet. Can it be done another way?

I know this question is off subject but I get fast responses here. and its somehow related :)

Comment: The 'put online' doesn't require you to be connected to the Internet.  What that does is allow other machines on your local network (or on the Internet) access to your machine.  Otherwise, only your local machine itself will be able to access the web server via http://127.0.0.1  If you run Start -> Run -> cmd.exe Then at command prompt type ipconfig, you can see the IP address of your machine running WAMP.  Put that in the URL of other machines on your local network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either your local IP or your hostname on the network.

For the hostname to work, your network needs a DNS server that updates itself from DHCP, or has a static entry for your computer, or all the systems need to have NetBEUI running. If you can type "ping " in a command prompt/console window, and it shows it pinging your network IP, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

they have to enter your ip

Answer (score 0):

You could use your local network IP address to address your machine. But you have to configure your webserver to deliver the right content without a specific host name.